# Marvel plugin not finding .properties file

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

I've been stuck on this for about a day. I downloaded and installed ElasticSearch 2.3.3 on my redhat vm. I am trying to follow the get started video on the site but not one of the installation commands from the video has worked for me, so I've tried following installation methods from the guide.

I downloaded the rpm and entered the following commands to install:

```
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch
bin/plugin -DproxyHost=... -DproxyPort=... install license
bin/plugin -DproxyHost=... -DproxyPort=... install marvel-agent
```

I then started my ElasticSearch node and went to localhost:9200/_plugin/marvel but nothing popped up.

I then thought it might be because I only downloaded the agent and not marvel, so I tried installing marvel from the cmd line, but I constantly getting a FileNotFound exception

```
bin/plugin -DproxyHost=... -DproxyPort=... install marvel
```

I then manually downloaded marvel-2.3.3.tar.gz and tried installing it manually

```
bin/plugin -DproxyHost=... -DproxyPort=... install --verbose file://.../marvel-2.3.3.tar.gz
```

but I'm told the zip is missing a plugin-descriptor.properties file

```
Verifying file:/home1/isuser/Downloads/marvel-2.3.3.tar.gz checksums if available ...
NOTE: Unable to verify checksum for downloaded plugin (unable to find .sha1 or .md5 file to verify)
ERROR: Could not find plugin descriptor 'plugin-descriptor.properties' in plugin zip
```

I then unzipped marvel-2.3.3.tar, added a .properties file, rezipped, and reinstalled. still got the same error.

I really need some help. This is very frustrating. I still need to install Kibana but if that installation is anything near as infuriating as this one I'm not looking forward to it...

**EDIT**:

I got past this error by moving the .properties file from within the `marvel` directory to the same level, but now I'm getting a new error. it keeps giving me a `FileNotFoundException`.

```
[root@den01ejm elasticsearch]# bin/plugin install -DproxyHost=www-proxy.us.oracle.com -DproxyPort=80 --verbose /home1/isuser/Desktop/up/marvel-2.3.3.tar.gz 
-> Installing /home1/isuser/Desktop/up/marvel-2.3.3.tar.gz...
Trying https://download.elastic.co//home1/home1-isuser.zip ...
Failed: FileNotFoundException[https://download.elastic.co//home1/home1-isuser.zip]; nested: FileNotFoundException[https://download.elastic.co//home1/home1-isuser.zip]; 
Trying https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=/home1/isuser/home1-isuser.zip ...
Failed: FileNotFoundException[https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=/home1/isuser/home1-isuser.zip]; nested: FileNotFoundException[https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=/home1/isuser/home1-isuser.zip]; 
Trying https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/content//home1/isuser/home1-isuser.zip ...
Failed: FileNotFoundException[https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/content//home1/isuser/home1-isuser.zip]; nested: FileNotFoundException[https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/content//home1/isuser/home1-isuser.zip]; 
Trying https://github.com//home1/archive/isuser.zip ...
Failed: FileNotFoundException[https://github.com//home1/archive/isuser.zip]; nested: FileNotFoundException[https://github.com//home1/archive/isuser.zip]; 
Trying https://github.com//home1/archive/master.zip ...
Failed: FileNotFoundException[https://github.com//home1/archive/master.zip]; nested: FileNotFoundException[https://github.com//home1/archive/master.zip]; 
ERROR: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get detailed information
```

Comment: Where did you download `marvel-2.3.3.zip`? I ask because you noted that but then the error notes a `.tar.gz`.

Comment: from the link provided in this site: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/installing-marvel.html#offline-installation . it was a .`.tar.gz` file, i made a typo in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch
bin/plugin -DproxyHost=... -DproxyPort=... install license
bin/plugin -DproxyHost=... -DproxyPort=... install marvel-agent
```

This is all that needs to be installed in **Elasticsearch** 2.x to make Marvel monitor Elasticsearch. The Marvel Agent monitors the node, with a dependency on the license plugin, then ships the data where ever it's configured to go (to the same node, by default).

The *third* plugin that you're trying to install is the Marvel UI component. Starting with ES 2.x, the UI component is a part of **Kibana** and not **Elasticsearch**.

As such, you should be installing that plugin in Kibana. As you are trying to use Marvel 2.3.3, you should be using Kibana 4.5 (so Kibana 4.5.1 as of now). From Kibana, you can install it there:

```
bin/kibana plugin --install elasticsearch/marvel/latest
```

**NOTE**: The syntax of the plugin commands will change in Elasticsearch 5.x and Kibana 5.x *and* this will be greatly simplified to literally being the same file for *both* Elasticsearch and Kibana, but both applications will still be needed for both sides: monitoring and the UI.

```
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install x-pack
bin/kibana-plugin install x-pack
```

Comment: I tried installing through kibana as recommended on that guide but I am behind a proxy. do you know the proxy options for the bin/kibana command? I tried -DproxyHost but I got "unknown option -D"

Comment: `-DproxyHost` (et al) are Java system properties. Kibana is written using node.js, so it doesn't use them. Kibana's script apparently doesn't expose a mechanism for using a proxy, so you'll _have_ to use the local installation approach: `bin/kibana plugin --install marvel --url file://path/to/file` Note that you must supply the name when using this approach.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I'll just respond here only so you don't have to respond to two threads. So I entered the bin/kibana command specifying the absolute path and I now get a `ENOTDIR: not a directory, unlink /file/to/kibana-4.5.1-linux-x64/installedPlugins/.plugin.installing/archive.part`. Do you know what this might be? If this is a different issue I can make a new post about it.

Comment: That's just the goofiness of `file:/` Depending on your system, I've found you need either an extra `/` or to drop a `/`. Try `file:/path/to/marvel-2.3.3.tar.gz`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix it. I'll make a new post on the Elastic forums. ElasticSearch doesn't seem to get too much visibility here :/ . Thanks for the help!

Comment: We come and go. I basically appear in batch intervals. :)

Comment: As a note: this was cross-posted in the Elastic forums and it was resolved there. The above instructions worked, but he was trying to use the modified tar file with Kibana and that's what was causing the ENOTDIR issue. Once he used the "real" one, it worked.